# bootstrap и css <a>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Решил поучить bootstrap. Делал по примеру на видео. Там парень менял свойства `<a>` в css и у него всё норм работало. Я пишу так же, но у меня не работает.

```css
a {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: crimson;
  background-color: brown;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">HOME</a>
```

Срабатывает только `background-color`, а на `color`, `:focus`, `:hover` нет реакции. Если отключить bootstrap, то норм. В чём проблема?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
    <meta name="vieport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    
    
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OLOL<i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a>
        </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Cats</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dogs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rats</a></li>
                    </ul>
        
                </div>
    
    </div>
 <
    
    
</div>   
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Bellefair');

body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: green;
    height: 500px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Bellefair;
    }


a {
font-size: 50px;
color: crimson;
}

a:hover,a:focus{
    
    color: darkred;
}

.fa-circle{
    color:coral;
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: В дополнение к совету сверху, советую пользоваться <a href="https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome">режимом</a> разработчика в браузере( на F12 в Хроме). Через него можно увидеть какие свойства и из какого css-файла активны, а какие нет и почему.

Answer (score 5):

Всё работает, если свои стили подключать после бутстрапа, а не до:

```html
<link rel=stylesheet href=//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css>

<style>
a {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: crimson;
  background-color: brown;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: yellow;
}
</style>

<a href="#">Home</a>
```

PS: А заглавные буквы надо делать через `text-transform: uppercase`.

Comment: у меня вот так
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
в head. <a> меняю в style и не работает

Comment: body в style меняется, а вот с <a> только бгколор

Comment: Составь [mcve] и добавь в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил, смотри.Body работает без проблем.